# fit method in keras (shape of the array)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

While compiling my code in the fit transform method it is showing an error about the shape of the array 
"
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (11,)"

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd



dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values


from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_x_1 = LabelEncoder()
x[:, 1] = labelencoder_x_1.fit_transform(x[:, 1])
labelencoder_x_2 = LabelEncoder()
x[:, 2] = labelencoder_x_2.fit_transform(x[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features =[1])
x = onehotencoder.fit_transform(x).toarray()
x =x[:, 1:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size =0.2, random_state =0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()


classifier.add(Dense(output_dim =6, init = 'uniform', activation= 'relu', input_dim= 6))

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim =6, init = 'uniform', activation= 'relu' ))

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim =1, init = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid' ))

classifier.compile(optimizer ='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])

classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)

y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: You told the model that the input is 6-dimensional, while in reality is it 11-dimensional. Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepency is in `x_train` and possibly `x_test`. If you look at `print(x_train.shape)` you'll probably get something like `(N, 11)` where N is the number of samples each containing 11 features. But wait, your model is defined to have 6 `input_dim` features. So you can:

- either change the `input_dim=11` in the first layer
- or look at the preprocessing to make sure you get back 6 features.